# Consider the differential equation: $y'=\frac{x^2}{1-y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i) 
Is the function given implicitly as $y^3-3y+x^3+2=0$ a solution for all $-\infty < 0 < \infty$?

ii) Find all solutions (the general solution) of this differential equation and write down the intervals where they are defined

I think I managed to solve the second problem, but I'm not sure though, the general solution I got was $3y-y^3-x^3=3C$ and that's defined on $(-\infty,\infty$) but I do not know about the first questions, any tips/solutions? thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This equation is of separable variables. $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2}{1-y^2} \Rightarrow (1-y^2) dy=x^2 dx$$ Then integrate both sides to give the general solution.

**Added:** When you integrate both sides, this give us: $$\int (1-y^2) dy=\int x^2 dx+C$$ equivalently $$y-\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{x^3}{3}=C$$ this is an implicit solution of the ODE. Where $C$ is any constant, multiply each sides by $-3$ and taking $C=\frac{2}{3}$ give us the desired solution.

Comment: that doesnt help me solve any of the questions.

Comment: Why you say that this no help?

Comment: If you are worried about the interval in where the solutions are defined. You can solve $y$ explicitly and the solutions are of the form $y=\sqrt[3]{p(x)}$ and the cubic root are well defined in the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation is "exact" with potential function $$\Phi(x,y)=y-\frac{1}{3}y^{3}-\frac{1}{3}x^{3}.$$
The level sets of this function $\Phi(x,y)=C$ determine the solutions to this ODE.  In particular,
$$y^{3}-3y+x^{3}=C$$ (after multiplying by $-3$).  So yes, your equation does define a solution implicitly, specifically, the one corresponding to $C=-2.$

Comment: mmh this is what it says in the solution manual, but I rly dont understad anything of it: the function y(x)defined as y^3−3y+x^3+2=0 take value y(0)=1 which is a singular point of x^2/1-y^2 so the function y(x) is a solution on interval x € (-inf,0) U (0,inf) not for all real numbers. i.e for i) I guess

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the first question is a NO.

For any fixed $x$, the expression $y^3 - 3y + x^3+2$ is a cubic polynomial in $y$. 
One can compute corresponding discriminant $\Delta(x)$ and find

$$\Delta(x) = 108 - 27(x^3+2)^2$$

For $x \in (-\infty, -\sqrt[3]{4}) \cup (0,\infty)$, $\Delta(x) < 0$ and the cubic polynomial in $y$ has a unique root. We can view $y$ as a function $y_0(x)$ over this union of intervals.

For $x \in (-\sqrt[3]{4}, 0)$, $\Delta(x) > 0$ and the cubic polynomials has three possible 
roots. We will view these 3 roots as 3 functions of $x$ over $(-\sqrt[3]{4}, 0 )$. Let's call them $y_1(x), y_2(x)$ and $y_3(x)$ and WOLOG, we will order them such that

$$y_1(x) > y_2(x) > y_3(x)$$

The first question now becomes whether you can pick one of these three functions,
join it with $y_0(x)$ and obtain a function continuous over all $\mathbb{R}$.

If you make a implicit plot of $y^3 - 3y + x^3 + 2$, you will notice one can either

- join $y_1(x)$ to $y_{0}(x)$ on the left to get a continuous function on $(-\infty, 0)$.
- or join $y_3(x)$ to $y_{0}(x)$ on the right to get a continuous function on $(-\sqrt[3]{4}, \infty )$.

However, there is no way to join them to create a function continuous over the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

[image: a plot of y^3 - 3 y + x^3 + 2]